# Yslow, Add Expires headers doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, seo, yslow

So, i have Yslow and i'm trying to ADD Expires headers.

So i have a `.htaccess` on the root of my website :

```
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"  
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\\.(xml|txt)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, public, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\\.(html|htm|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

I have enable mod_headers and mod_expires :

```
root@heisenberg:~# a2enmod headers
Module headers already enabled

root@heisenberg:~# a2enmod expires
Module expires already enabled
```

But no effect, i have ALWAYS "F" with Yslow... What can i do for that ? I have already read the others topics of stackoverflow....

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

When faced with a similar problem, the following link helped me set up expires headers on Apache. 
http://www.simonwhatley.co.uk/how-to-set-an-expires-header-in-apache.
Adding **ExpiresActive On** before and **ExpiresByType** inside the document module in the project configuration in httpd.conf did the trick for me.
Maybe this helps you too.

Also, I did not need to add Cache-Control to headers. They were automatically added to the headers. I'm not a pro but this is what I observed.